# Attachment.Delete fails for 2007

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

In outlook 2007. This is only for the RTF format.

```
void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mail = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
            mail.Save();
            Outlook.Attachments attachments = mail.Attachments as Outlook.Attachments;

            if (attachments != null)
            {
                int iTotalAttachments = attachments.Count;
                for (int i = iTotalAttachments; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    Outlook.Attachment attachment = attachments[i] as Outlook.Attachment;

                    // Need to make sure the attachment is not inline
                    if (attachment != null && attachment.Type != Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olOLE)
                    {
                        attachment.Delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

However, if I attach multiple attachments. Typically for the second attachment - I get a message "The operation Failed".

This is happening for 2007. Not for 2010 and 2013. instead of attachment.Delete()
 mail.Attachments.Remove(i);

However the following code works on 2007On 2010 and 2013, it doesn't do a proper removal for the attachment (you can see the icon in the email body) ?

Comment: look at this posting you will have to convert it to C# http://www.outlookcode.com/threads.aspx?forumid=2&messageid=26228 look at `Sue Mosher   31-Mar-2008  13:28` response second from the bottom of the page

Comment: Saving the mail before the operation - I did not resolve the issue.

Comment: have you stepped thru the code to verify that attachment has valid information can you report back what it displays on the first and second iteration ..?

Comment: Yes. I have stepped through the code. I get a COMException with {"The operation failed."}. It consistently happens on 2007 and on the 2nd iteration. The attachments are simple text files.

Comment: Ok with what little bit of code you have shown.. where are you initially creating / instantiating the `COMInterop object..? can you show all relevant code

Comment: Updated the entire code from a simple scratch outlook Addin application built using VSTO in visual studio 2010.

Comment: Hi, @SaniaProgrammer i know this was a long time ago, but have you found the solution yet? I am facing the same issue and i find no posts on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an exception only in the ItemSend event handler? I'd suggest using another place for such code.